# 404 ошибка в битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс, url, чпу

На странице с каталогом товара стоит компонент `bitrix:catalog.section.list`

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section.list", 
    "naznachenie", 
    array(
        "VIEW_MODE" => "TILE",
        "SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "2",
        "SECTION_ID" => $row["ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
        "TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
        "SECTION_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_NOTES" => "",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "naznachenie",
        "HIDE_SECTION_NAME" => "N"
    ),
    false
);
```

УРЛ включен

Ссылка на раздел выглядит вот так `www.mysite.ru/catalog/radel`

Папка `раздел` физически существует на сервере, и в ней лежит `index.php`, вот код

```
<?php
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Раздел");
?>




<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Переходя по www.mysite.ru/catalog/radel, я вижу шапку и футер моего сайта, все работает.

Но если в это index.php я добавляю компонент `bitrix:catalog.section` вот так

```
<?php
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("");
?>


<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section",
    "",
    Array(
        "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
        "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "MORE_PHOTO",
        "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "UF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE",
        "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php",
        "BRAND_PROPERTY" => "BRAND_REF",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "COMPATIBLE_MODE" => "Y",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "Y",
        "CURRENCY_ID" => "RUB",
        "CUSTOM_FILTER" => "",
        "DATA_LAYER_NAME" => "dataLayer",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
        "DISCOUNT_PERCENT_POSITION" => "bottom-right",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "ENLARGE_PRODUCT" => "PROP",
        "ENLARGE_PROP" => "NEWPRODUCT",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE_OFFERS" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "2",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "LABEL_PROP" => array("NEWPRODUCT"),
        "LABEL_PROP_MOBILE" => array(),
        "LABEL_PROP_POSITION" => "top-left",
        "LAZY_LOAD" => "Y",
        "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
        "LOAD_ON_SCROLL" => "N",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
        "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
        "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
        "MESS_BTN_LAZY_LOAD" => "Показать ещё",
        "MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE" => "Подписаться",
        "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array("ARTNUMBER","COLOR_REF","SIZES_SHOES","SIZES_CLOTHES"),
        "OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
        "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "5",
        "OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("COLOR_REF","SIZES_SHOES","SIZES_CLOTHES",""),
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "OFFER_ADD_PICT_PROP" => "MORE_PHOTO",
        "OFFER_TREE_PROPS" => array("COLOR_REF","SIZES_SHOES","SIZES_CLOTHES"),
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
        "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "18",
        "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array("BASE"),
        "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
        "PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER" => "price,props,sku,quantityLimit,quantity,buttons,compare",
        "PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE" => "Y",
        "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
        "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array("NEWPRODUCT","MATERIAL"),
        "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
        "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "",
        "PRODUCT_ROW_VARIANTS" => "[{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false},{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':false},{'VARIANT':'2','BIG_DATA':true}]",
        "PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION" => "Y",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array("NEWPRODUCT",""),
        "PROPERTY_CODE_MOBILE" => array(),
        "RCM_PROD_ID" => $_REQUEST["PRODUCT_ID"],
        "RCM_TYPE" => "personal",
        "SECTION_CODE" => "pants",
        "SECTION_ID" => "",
        "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array("",""),
        "SEF_MODE" => "N",
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "N",
        "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",
        "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "Y",
        "SHOW_FROM_SECTION" => "N",
        "SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY" => "N",
        "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "N",
        "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
        "SHOW_SLIDER" => "Y",
        "SLIDER_INTERVAL" => "3000",
        "SLIDER_PROGRESS" => "N",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "USE_ENHANCED_ECOMMERCE" => "Y",
        "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
        "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
        "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N"
    )
);?>



<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

То ловлю 404 ошибку.

Почему это происходит , и как исправить? 
Спасибо.

Comment: а что в коде страницы 404.php написано?

Comment: А почему на страницу с каталогом товаров не повесить комплексный компонент `catalog` и не мучаться?

Comment: Если используете связку 2 компонентов, то вы должны в компонент `catalog.section` передавать идентификатор раздела. А еще необходимо проверить настройку ЧПУ у инфоблока и компонента `catalog.section.list`

Comment: @NikolajSarry у меня так и работает, на странице содержимого раздела весит catalog.section, которому передаётся SECTION_CODE из url`a, через urlrewrite.php. Все заработало. Теперь не знаю как сделать страницу одного товара. Правило #/catalog/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/# перебивает правило  #/catalog/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/#  =) Как этого избежать ? не знаете?

Comment: @NikolajSarry из-за неправильного SECTION_CODE в компоненте была 404